# 'Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int' when left join temp tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by, sum

When trying to LEFT JOIN two temp tables I have, I'm getting the arithmetic overflow error. When doing a UNION, there's no issue, nor is there an issue when I change my SELECT statement to not use SUM functions. Here are my two tables:

```
SELECT SUM(count) count
     , EventType
     , month
FROM #engine_final
GROUP BY EventType
       , month
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(count) count
     , EventType
     , month
FROM #circumvent_final
GROUP BY EventType
       , month
```

And here's the results:

[image]

So what I'm attempting to do is SUM my counts, grouped by month, with the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(ef.count) AS EngineStarts
     , SUM(cf.count) AS Circumventions
FROM #engine_final ef
     LEFT JOIN #circumvent_final cf ON ef.month = cf.month
```

But this is when I'm confronted with the error. I thought maybe I had hit the limit for INT, but my numbers only reach about 260 million, so that can't be it. What am I missing?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your join multiplies the rows. You should pre-aggregate in subqueries first, then join:

```
SELECT ef.month, ef.EngineStarts, cf.Circumventions
FROM (
    SELECT month, SUM(count) EngineStarts
    FROM #engine_final 
    GROUP BY month
) ef
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT month, SUM(cf.count) AS Circumventions
    FROM #circumvent_final 
    GROUP BY month
) cf ON ef.month = cf.month
```

I am unsure whether you need `where` clauses in the subquery to filter on the `eventType` - you can easily add them if that's needed.

If you have months in `cf` that are not in `ef`, and the other way around too, you might want to consider a `FULL JOIN` instead of a  `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(ef.month, cf.month) month, 
    COALESCE(ef.EngineStarts, 0) EngineStarts, 
    COALESCE(cf.Circumventions, 0) Circumventions
FROM (
    SELECT month, SUM(count) EngineStarts
    FROM #engine_final 
    GROUP BY month
) ef
FULL JOIN (
    SELECT month, SUM(cf.count) AS Circumventions
    FROM #circumvent_final 
    GROUP BY month
) cf ON ef.month = cf.month
```

Comment: Outstanding, thank you so much. I don't understand why my original method was "multiplying" the rows, however. Might I bother you for an explanation of that? I thought it was simply going to SUM the counts based on their existence with the correct month?

Comment: @jw11432: there are multiple rows in both tables that have the same month, so the `join` generates a cartesian products of these. So you end up summing the same value multiple times instead of just once.